# Exe4j splash screen does not go away after upgrading to 6.0.1

Tags: java, rcp, exe4j

I recently upgraded from exe4j 4.6 to 6.0.1 and now the splash screen doesn't go away until i close the application.

Our old exe4j configuration options for splash used autoOff="true" which doesn't look like it exists anymore. The manual suggests there might be something called windowsNative to create a splash controlled by the executable , but this didn't work either.  The manual also suggests you could add Controller.hide() from the exe4jlib.jar.  I couldn't get this to work.  It is wrapped in a try catch block and the catch isn't triggered but the splash doesn't hide.  The mainClass being called is org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main as it is an eclipse RCP.

Original Config for the splash.
    `<splashScreen show="true" autoOff="true" alwaysOnTop="false" width="500" height="325" bitmapFile="splash.bmp" java6SplashScreen="false">`

Attempted config.
    `<splashScreen show="true" windowsNative="true" width="500" height="325" bitmapFile="splash.bmp" textOverlay="true">`

Expected:
Run executable
See Splash
Splash goes away when login screen appears.

Actual:
Run Executable
See Splash
Splash never goes away until application is closed.

Update: Thinking it might be more of an issue with how exe4j interacts with RCP.  It is RCP 3.x

Comment: exe4j 6 uses the Java splash screen, there is no separate implementation of the splash screen anymore. Does calling `java.awt.SplashScreen.getSplashScreen().close()` hide the splash screen?

Comment: That worked! Thanks!